# How to add opened files to Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio

I open some source files in `Visual Studio` IDE editor.  These files are not included in a `Visual Studio` project yet.  How may I add files to project I want?  Is there any quick way to add opened file to project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the quickest way is to right click the tab that is your opened file and select *Open Containing Folder*. Then simply drag your file onto your project (or some directory in your project) to add it